# why is the variable offset not changing?

Tags: reactjs, types

when offset is pressed does not change why this behavior occurs

I have several sliders and each slider has such a problem

```
   const left = (refSlider:any, offset:number) => {
    offset += 180
    refSlider.current.style.left = offset + 'px'
    console.log(offset)// 1 click = 180 , 2 click = 180
}

    <div className="left-button" onClick={() => left(refSliderHp, offsetHP)}>
let offsetHP:number = 0
```

Comment: What’s the value of ‘offsetHP‘?

Comment: let offsetHP:number = 0

Comment: If you want `offset` to increment, than `offsetHP` must too, right? If it's always zero than it will always be 180 at your console log.

Comment: offset is offsehp. Since I am passing it to the function

Comment: offset in your function is the value of offsetHP, not offsetHP itself. Incrementing offset is not incrementing offsetHP. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use setState instead of normal variable

```
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
```

Your function Logic

```
 const left = (refSlider:any, offset:number) => {
  setOffset((state) => state + 180);
//...rest of code
```

}